# bind kendo dropdownlist from controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, kendo-ui

I'm trying to populate kendo dropdownlist after selection of another dropdownlist.
Here is my code for my View:

```
function ItemTypeList(e) {
    var itemType = $("#txtItemTypeName").data("kendoDropDownList").text();
    var brandName = $("#txtBrandName").data("kendoDropDownList").text();


    $.ajax({
        url: "/Accountability/GetSpecificationList",
        data: { 'items': itemType + '|' + brandName  },
        datatype: "json",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#txtSpecification').data('kendoDropDownList').dataSource.data(data);
        },
        error: function () {

        }
    });
}
```

Here is my code for my Controller:

```
public string GetSpecificationList(string items)
    {
        string sql = "";
        var obj = items.Split('|');

        sql = @"select specification from AIMS.mItem 
                 where ItemTypeID=(select ItemTypeID from AIMS.mItemType where ItemTypeName='" + obj[0] + @"') 
                 and BrandID=(select BrandID from AIMS.mBrand where BrandName='"+ obj[1]+@"')
                 order by Specification";

        DataTable dt = function.ExecuteQuery(sql);
        string data = dt.Rows[0]["specification"].ToString();
        return data;
    }
```

Here is my code for the dropdownlist:
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.xSpecificationList) .Name("txtSpecification") .DataValueField("specification") .DataTextField("specification") .HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "width: 100%" }) .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)@ViewBag.xSpecificat‌​ionList) .Filter("contains") .OptionLabel("- Select -")

I am not getting any error however the result displayed in dropdownlist is 'undefined' [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHbt2.jpg)

Can someone help me? I get stucked by this.

Comment: show your dropdown configuration. Most likely you are missing `dataTextField` and `dataValueField`

Comment: Kudos for posting a question about a widget **without** the widget's code.

Comment: This is my code for dropdown.   
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.xSpecificationList)
                    .Name("txtSpecification")
                    .DataValueField("specification")
                    .DataTextField("specification")
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "width: 100%" })
                    .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)@ViewBag.xSpecificationList)
                   
                    .Filter("contains")
                    .OptionLabel("- Select -")